# Install google apps market place app on a test domain

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I'm working on converting our app from oAuth1 to oAuth2 and I'd like to install and test it on a domain, other than the one I'm using. 
Right now, in the google apps marketplace SDK there is a button that says: Test Install Flow but that only installs on the current domain.

Is there a way to share an install link so that someone on another domain can install the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Test Link is only for initial tests. If you want to properly test the app, you need to list in the Chrome Webstore as a [private listing](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2649489).